# jQuery code not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

The following jQuery code works in all browsers that I've tested it with, except for Internet Explorer:

```
$("#post-body").click(function() {
   $('.submit-post').slideDown('slow', function() {});
});
```

Can anyone help me understand why it's not working, and how I can resolve it? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I think this question should be re-titled to "Internet Explorer not working with jQuery correctly."  Your jQuery looks fine off the top of my head, it's IE that's broken and as Diodeus said, you just have to work around it.

Answer (score 3):

Try getting rid on the empty anonymous function:

```
 $("#post-body").click(function() {
    $('.submit-post').slideDown('slow');
   });
```

Comment: +1. that was about to be my comment.  What is in that function!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $("#post-body").live("click", function() {
        $('.submit-post').slideDown('slow');
    });
```